# How to combine nested types into one

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, types

```
const type typesFromConst = typeof CONSTANT = {
   first: string
   second: {
      importStuff-one: {
         propA: string[]
      }
      importStuff-two: {
         propA: string[]
      }
   }
}
```

And I passing somewhere "importStuff-one" or "importStuff-two" as a props

so to get type of this one I need to write this spaghetti:

```
Props: {
   propsOneOrTwo: typesFromConst["second"]["importStuff-one"] | typesFromConst["second"]["importStuff-two"]
}
```

How to shortcut this one to something shorter?
I mean how to combine that nested types to have something shorter?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand those minuses...
I figure it out by myself:

```
Props: {
   propsOneOrTwo: typesFromConst["second"][keyof typesFromConst["second"]]
}
```